# Retreive images uploaded via Infopath

Tags: 2007, infopath

I'm relatively new to SharePoint and got stuck with this problem:

I've created an Infopath formular the user can fill out and submit. One part of this infopath formular is a function to upload an image. Now I want to query and display those inputs on a separate Website. I managed to display all (text) Information using customized webparts but am unable to embed the uploaded image.

The idea is to dynamically create a "Report" site that simply embeds the uploaded images.

Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Do you mean an InfoPath 'form' or something else?

Comment: How did you configure the function to upload the images?

Comment: Yes, an InfoPath 'form'. 
I use the Fileattachment function - and didn't configure anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this post: http://spappdev.blogspot.com/2009/03/programatically-extract-attachments.html

If you write the image to a picture library instead of a document library it should work for you.